# Updating to Hibernate 5.1 from 3.6 produce Non-entity object instance passed to evict exception

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, evict, hibernate-5

I was working with a hibernate 3.6 project which use annotations for mapping and now I migrate it to hibernate 5.1 and i have this run time exception  **Non-entity object instance passed to evict** 
Below is the call to evict

```
HibernateUtils.getSession().evict(origProject.getProbidinfo());
HibernateUtils.getSession().evict(origProject);
```

And below is the code from DefaultEvictEventListener.class from where the exception is throwing

```
EntityPersister persister = null;
                final String entityName = persistenceContext.getSession().guessEntityName( object );
                if ( entityName != null ) {
                    try {
                        persister = persistenceContext.getSession().getFactory().getEntityPersister( entityName );
                    }
                    catch (Exception ignore) {
                    }
                }
                if ( persister == null ) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Non-entity object instance passed to evict : " + object );
                }
```

where persister is null in my case in hibernate 5.1.
I can provide further details, if its not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception "Non-entity object instance passed to evict" was ignored by hibernate until version 4.2, which now throws:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-entity object instance passed to evict.

In hibernate versions before 4.2, it was ignored by not having an else part for [DefaultEvictEventListener.java#L91-L94](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultEvictEventListener.java#L91-L94).

Starting with version 4.2, the else part was added as we can see at [DefaultEvictEventListener.java#L99-L115](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultEvictEventListener.java#L99-L115).

The only proposal which I find on the web after my research for this bug is that we catch and ignore this exception.

However, even if its not a perfect solution I think, ommitting the evict call, which cause the exception is what I prefer as I am okay this to be in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate checks the object you passed is entity, so it does not want to evict or detach any object (in my case it was ArrayList) or null except entity.

I prefer null check or type check for the solutions rather than catch and ignore.